# HTML5 Video "currentTime" causing video to disappear and not show. IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a website that I have got a video that plays when you scroll your cursor around on it, or when you click dots to the right of it to skip to different parts of the video. This works great in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, however it's not quite working all right in IE.

The video plays when you scroll down on it, however when you try to skip around using the dots on the right of it the video never shows back up.

The video is on here: 
http://elopaypoint.staging.wpengine.com/#feature-rich

The JavaScript can be found here: 
http://elopaypoint.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/elotouch-v2/js/video.source.js

I can't seem to find anyone that is having the same problem.

Comment: what version of IE are you using? have you tried compatibility mode yet?

Comment: I tested in IE 10, and other team members have tested in IE 11

Comment: have you tried compatibility mode on either 10 or 11?

Comment: I just tried it now and it made everything even worse.. Broke the entire site basically..

Comment: Fantastic. Gotta love IE. *sarcasm*